# How to implement google place pin in camera

Tags: android, google-maps, augmented-reality

I am using augmented reality in my application. So i have to implement an application, after running my application, device camera will open and when i will move this camera i will get Google map places like hotel,dominoes, on that place any pin will show, after clicked on that pin details of hotel, dominoes will be display. If any one know about please tell me or if any one have code related give me.

Firstly i have did how to get the Google place on map right now i have to open camera in my application and i want to show pin of places in my camera

Comment: Welcome to [so].  On [so] and other Stack Exchange sites, it's expected that you show what you have attempted to do to see the issue or research/understanding about the problem.  Could you edit your post to provide some information as to specifics about your problem and what you're actually having trouble with?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try out this demo code. Click [here](https://github.com/raweng/augmented-reality-view/)!.. It will help you.

You can get source code from this link. I have implemented the same using this code. It works.

I have edited link.. from this link, you can download the zip file.

Comment: It's an apk...not a code... mention a direct link to the source code.